# VB.NET: Windows Image Acquisition 2 duplex scan

Tags: vb.net, wia

I got the following code for duplex scanning which uses WIA2 for communication with scanners. It works perfectly with Fujitsu fi-6130 but there is an issue with Epson GT-S55. The problem is, it saves the second image of the duplex scan blank (in black color). Is there a property that I'm missing here?.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ADFScan()
End Sub

Public Sub ADFScan()
    Dim WiaDialog1 As New WIA.CommonDialog
    Dim WiaDevice1 As WIA.Device = WiaDialog1.ShowSelectDevice(WIA.WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, False, False)

    WiaDevice1.Properties("3088").let_Value("4")    'WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT = 3088, DUPLEX = 4

    Dim Image1 As WIA.ImageFile = DirectCast(WiaDevice1.Items(1).Transfer(WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatBMP), WIA.ImageFile)     'Paper side A
    Dim Image2 As WIA.ImageFile = DirectCast(WiaDevice1.Items(1).Transfer(WIA.FormatID.wiaFormatBMP), WIA.ImageFile)     'Paper side B

    Image1.SaveFile("C:\SideA.bmp")
    Image2.SaveFile("C:\SideB.bmp")
End Sub
```

I tried setting the WIA_DPS_PAGES property to 1 as suggested in [C# WIA with Automatic Document Feeder (ADF) retuns only one page on certain scanners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331498/c-sharp-wia-with-automatic-document-feeder-adf-retuns-only-one-page-on-certain) but it didn't worked.

These are some of the properties set by default for the Epson scanner.

```
Property name                     ID    Value
--------------------------------------------------------------
Document Handling Capabilities    3086     33
Document Handling Select          3088      1
Document Handling Capacity        3089    100
Pages                             3096      0
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After a lot of research and testing, i realized that WIA2 has a completely different behavior with different scanners irrelevant of the properties that you may set. So, in order to use the feeder and duplex property of my scanners, I finally decided to try TWAIN. I found a great open source project called TwainDotNet https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet which is based on another great project the openTWAIN http://opentwain.codeplex.com/. It contains all the dlls for the communication and sample code for VB.NET and C#.

Comment: You should try **WIA_DPS_DOCUMENT_HANDLING_SELECT** as found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/image/wia-dps-document-handling-select