# Scan from Automatic Document Feeder (ADF) with recent printers

Tags: c#, oracle-adf, printers, scanning, wia

I want to scan multiple pages from the ADF of a recent printer. I'm using WIA library. The problem is, with older printers, the ADF just take one page and then wait for the next command, but with the printer I actually have (Epson WF-2520), it just take 1 page, then the second, then the third without stopping and waiting for another command which returns me the first picture only. If I force the famous boolean value "hasMorePages" to true, it returns me an error because ADF is already in use.

This question: [C# WIA with Automatic Document Feeder (ADF) retuns only one page on certain scanners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331498/c-sharp-wia-with-automatic-document-feeder-adf-retuns-only-one-page-on-certain) explains my issue, but the solution he found didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who wants to know what appens, I just asked my client if he would agree to change the printer. He did agree.

When I called the Epson Support they told me that this printer was not the best printer to do things like that.

With a better printer "WP 4535" the software worked like a charm.