# Number of Pages Scanned

Tags: c#, wia

Is there anyway to pull what page number count of scanned images from the scanner in WIA c#

I'm using c# and WIA. The only other option is the endorser but i don't know how to set the values.

I would like to have an internal scan count and the scan count from the machine to compare and throw an error if they aren't in synch. I have noticed the scanner on occasion after 150 scans will feed a scan through count it on the machine but provide no images.

Comment: Maybe the answers here point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331498/c-sharp-wia-with-automatic-document-feeder-adf-retuns-only-one-page-on-certain

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Though I have no issues saving the images once they are scanned in Duplex mode.  The issue is on a rare occasion the scanner will pull page through count it on the scanners display screen but not actually scan it. So i miss a scan.